# How to extend initial uniform distribution of change points to the last 20% of data?

Tags: time-series, facebook-prophet

I'm using [Prophet](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) to detect significant change points in daily sales data.

I'd like to know by the end of each week or 2 weeks if there was a new candidate for a change point, that appeared in that recent time frame. But Prophet only puts candidate change points in the first 80%, so I have to limit data to 5-10 weeks long, which kills seasonality information.

What is the rational for using only first 80% of data?
Is it reasonable to try increase the number for the case described?
What would be a way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be available as a parameter in v0.3

Got a response from the Prophet team:
https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/515